# htaccess restrict acces to folder and subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Hi Im writing a Codeigniter application where i create some directories as I upload files.

How can I add a rule to my .htaccss file that disallows direct folder access to my upload folder, and its subfolders, while allowing access to the files in these folders?

My file structure looks like this

```
index.html
.htaccess
uploads/ <- No direct access allowed
uploads/gallery/ <- No direct access allowed
uploads/gallery/1 <- No direct access allowed
uploads/gallery/1/file1.jpg <- access is ok
uploads/gallery/1/file2.jpg <- access is ok
uploads/gallery/2 <- No direct access allowed
uploads/gallery/2/file3.jpg <- access is ok
uploads/gallery/2/file4.jpg <- access is ok
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file `/uploads/.htaccess` and have this code:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```